# Is it possible to add custom headers to a ServiceStack Redis message?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, messaging

When a message is sent to Redis using ServiceStack, the framework adds all the standard headers (`Priority`, `CreatedDate`, ...). However, is it possible to add any custom headers to that message? I've got a set of microservices that pass messages amongst each other, and I'd like to include a shared header.

So far, I have explored implementing my own version of IMessage or IMessageFactory, and I've looked at the different properties within `RedisMqServer` when boostrapping it in the IOC container, but I have yet to find anywhere I can add a new header.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `IMessage.Tag` to send any user defined tag text, e.g:

```
using (var mqClient = mqServer.CreateMessageQueueClient())
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Message<HelloIntro>(new Hello { Name = "World" }) {
        Tag = "Custom"
    });
}
```

Otherwise I've just added support for sending Custom Headers [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/e165a194ddc103ea2aca42a1eb9c2e9096eba5d5) which will now also let you send Custom Headers in the new `IMessage.Meta` string Dictionary, e.g:

```
using (var mqClient = mqServer.CreateMessageQueueClient())
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Message<HelloIntro>(new Hello { Name = "World" }) {
        Meta = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Custom", "Header" } }
    });
}
```

Which you can access in your MQ `RegisterHandler`, e.g:

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<Hello>(m =>
    new Message<HelloResponse>(new HelloResponse { 
        Result = "Hello, {0}!".Fmt(m.GetBody().Name) 
    }) { 
        Meta = m.Meta 
    });
```

Your MQ Handler can also now return an `IMessage` response which allows full round-tripping of any custom headers.

This change is available from v4.0.57 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks @mythz! I will definitely have to upgrade to the newest version of ServiceStack and take advantage of the Meta property! Thanks for implementing that in such short order! I was able to pass the tag just fine to Redis. Now, in terms of consuming it... do I have access to it over `GlobalMessageRequestFilters`? Otherwise, how would I access to it without having to get it on the `RegisterHandler` for every handler? Reason I'm asking also is, I have my handlers set up as so: `message_server.RegisterHandler<MyRequest>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);` Thanks again!

Comment: @napo You'd need to cast `IRequest` to `BasicRequest` to access the `BasicRequest.Message` property.

Comment: ! Thanks, that does the trick! I was trying to cast it as IMessage/Message and couldn't get anything out of it. Now I'm able to get it — perfect! Now, last question... is there a way to add the tag to every message, so I don't have to explicitly add it to every message that I build? Thanks again!

Comment: @napo You could potentially use `RedisMqServer.ResponseFilter` to inspect/modify or change the response that gets returned.